# How to have clean rounded borders using Flutter web?

Tags: flutter

I'm trying to implement Shadcn (https://ui.shadcn.com/) for Flutter web.
Shadcn uses very thin borders  and a radius of 8.0 for a large part of its components.

I'm currently working on the Card widget. Here's the CardTheme I've created:

```
final cardTheme = CardTheme(
  shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
    side: BorderSide(width: 0.1, color: themeColors.borderColor),
    borderRadius: const BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(8.0)),
  ),
);
```

[image: result]

The rounded borders are ugly and I can't figure out why.

I tried launching my app with the HTML renderer but it's even worse.

[image: Button]
[image: Card]

Have you ever encountered a similar problem, and if so, do you know how to solve it? Many thanks in advance!

Comment: what happen if you increase the border `width`

Comment: The rounded corners are ugly because they are brighter than the rest of the line. Just a guess: maybe that happens, because there is more color in them. A normal pixel with a straight .1 line only has 10% color. A border pixel with a diagonal .1 line has 14.14% of color.